Do mathematicians care about the validity ("truth") of the axioms?
Vladimir Arnold (b. 1937) once said that David Hilbert (b. 1862) and Bourbaki (f. 1934) "proclaimed that the goal of their science was the investigation of all corollaries of arbitrary systems of axioms." (Arnold: Swimming Against the Tide (2014), p. 5)
Some web searches tell me this is sometimes called the "if-then formalism" in the philosophy of mathematics.
Is mathematics a game of axioms/definitions/primitive notions/etc, and their logical consequences, that need not be checked in "reality"/"nature"? Or maybe the axioms of mathematics should have some relation to "reality"/"nature" to be considered relevant? For example, the axioms of Euclidean geometry are, at least approximately, valid in our everyday experience, aren't they? The ones of basic arithmetic too (these ones seem to be totally true in reality).
P.S. I wanted to conclude with a quote from Albert Einstein (b. 1879) on his position about this matter: "As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not certain; and as far as they are certain, they do not refer to reality." (https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Einstein_geometry/)

Yes of course. Mathematicians are interested into "interesting" theories, i.e. theories that speak about some "real" abstract structures. The "mathematics" of chess game is not interesting.

And Hilbert was NOT a "formalist" in the silly sense of the above quote. He was really interested into Cantor's paradise.

See Hilbert's Program: the key-point is the distinction between the "intuitive"part of mathematics and the "ideal" one.

Mathematicians love to pride themselves on their abstract arbitrarity, but it's more of a fantastical ideal than reality. Yes, in principle, these axioms are arbitrary, but they're chosen specifically such that they can produce objects like numbers and shapes; things we care about and use in daily life. If math were truly arbitrary, it would be far less cohesive, with mathematicians studying math in logics with no applications whatsoever. It's not a coincidence that the math we study has applications. it's chosen to be studied because it does, in fact.

It depends on whether you are talking about pure or applied mathematics. It may be that some area of pure mathematics has no real world application, or that an application happens along later after the theory is developed. With applied mathematics, there is an intended interpretation.

Probably depends on the philosophy of the mathematician in question. Some mathematicians are realists and monoists believing in "one true mathematics" probably inspired by Plato. Its these types of mathematicians that might have objected at the invention of complex numbers on the basis of them not being "real". Others might be pluralists and/or nominalists and not share this worry.

That mathematics is either an arbitrary formal game or uncovers truths of reality and nature is a false dichotomy. Some mathematicians believe one or the other (formalists and platonists, respectively), but most are pragmatic in their cares. They are drawn to problems that are 'useful' and/or 'interesting', which usually means akin to seemingly unrelated problems that come up elsewhere and hence reveal potentially useful connections. Something can be useful, as a tool or useful fiction, and be cared about as such without being 'true' of anything.

@Conifold, your comments about formalists and "games" are a caricature.  I suggest again that you read Abraham Robinson's essay Formalism 64.

It's not like mathematicians sit around all day dreaming up ever more fantastical axioms. Very few have ever introduced any new axioms. There must be infinitely many possible systems of axioms, but only a small handful have caught the interest of mathematicians for one reason or another including but not limited to real-world applications.

Speaking as a mathematician, yes we care. Most (if not all) of us are Platonists, though many are in the closet about that

How could one even know that an axiom is "false"?

There's a lot of confusion between:

axioms in foundational sense, which are, for most mathematicians, the ZFC axioms of set theory, and
axioms defining a class of mathematical objects, such as for example axioms of Vector space that underlies a modern definition of Euclidean geometry.

The former ones are closer to the Greek notion of "basic truths"; they are accepted by most mathematicians not so much because they are "true", but because they allow one to build, in an unambiguous way and free from contradictions, all mathematical objects that we care about.
For the latter ones, the question of "truth" does not make much sense - we are not making any claims, we are just giving a definition for future reference. Once we give a set of axioms, there are however some very valid questions: can we actually construct objects satisfying these axioms? If so, do some of these objects model anything in the real world, and how faithfully? If not, why do we care? Is anything actually gained by introducing these axioms, as compared to just studying concrete examples?
We can track this story in the case of vectors spaces: starting from ZFC axioms (in the sense 1) of set theory, we can construct natural numbers, then rational numbers, then real numbers, then the 3D Euclidean space. We can show that it does satisfies the axioms of Vector space, and it models quite faithfully something in the real world. As we study Linear algebra and its applications, we learn that it is useful to organize a part of our knowledge into theorems that are true for any vector space - say, of any dimension - not just the 3D Euclidean space. We prove such theorems (once and for all!) by deriving them from axioms of a vector space.
Arnold critique was that much of mathematical research is focused on axiom systems that don't correspond to anything in reality and thus are, in his opinion, not worthy of investigation, or maybe that introducing axioms and deriving general results from them adds nothing compared to the study of concrete objects satisfying these axioms. It should not be framed in terms of "truth" versus "non-truth" of the axioms. It was certainly a hyperbole then that mathematicians care about consequences of arbitrary sets of axioms though, and even less true now.
I think is it instructive to analyze the examples that you give.

The ones of basic arithmetic [...] seem to be totally true in reality.

I don't know about that. One of the axioms of arithmetics claims that every natural number n has a successor, n+1. We certainly cannot conclude from "everyday experience" whether this is true; we never counted more objects than the number of particles in the universe, say.  We cannot "infer inductively" from there, since we definitely know of examples when something is true for all integers up to the number of particles in the universe, but false in general. (There are actually mathematicians who contend that the axiom is false.)

the axioms of Euclidean geometry are, at least approximately, valid in our everyday experience, aren't they?

Again, they are not. For example, one of the axioms states that if two lines intersect, they intersect at a single point. This is blatantly false: if I draw two lines with a pencil and look closely, there will not be a single point of intersection, but a whole area with graphite particles from both lines, no matter how thin is the pencil. If it is really thin, the actual line may be a dotted line of carbon atoms, and there will be no intersection at all. If I model my lines e.g. with light rays, the result will be the same due to diffraction, quantum uncertainty etc.
Also, empirically, Euclidean axioms are no more "approximately true" than e.g. Lobachevski's. If we zoom in near any particular point of Lobachevski's plane, we approximately recover Euclidean geometry (similalry to how a sphere, at small scales compared to the radius, is nearly flat). So if you say our world is "approximately Euclidean", I can counter by saying it's "approximately Lobachevskian", with really tiny curvature that goes into your approximation error. The difference between the two axiom systems is about "two lines don't intersect" vs "we know they intersect, even if we could never prove it since the intersection 10000 times the size of the Universe from here," which is something that is manifestly not checkable empirically. Yet the two axiomatics are in direct contradiction with each other.
So, even in the simplest examples, it is problematic to speak about "truth of the axioms". Natural numbers, and Euclidean space, and quantum mechanics are useful to describe reality - we know that a posteriori and accept their axioms because they allow a simple, unambiguous definition of these mathematical objects.

This is an excellent answer. I do have two small nitpicks though. I think this would be helped by pointing out that Lobachevski's axioms essentially describe hyperbolic geometry. I think more people recognize the term hyperbolic geometry than Lobachevski's axioms in isolation. I also think you can emphasize a lot more that there are many types of non-euclidean geometry that see genuine applied usage outside of theory. Euclidean geometry does not apply in many, many real and applicable circumstances.

Nitpicking: it's not actually known that the first crossing between logarithmic integral and prime-counting function is larger than the number of atoms in the universe. According to Wikipedia, the currently known lower bound is in the order of 10^19, which is far less than that.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523191/why-use-the-word-axiom-rather-than-property

Even outside of mathematics, something that is as "obviously true" as even an axiom should be, might not be true at all. Just think of "Something cannot be both a particle and a wave"

Einstein’s answer to your question clearly says: Mathematician do not and cannot care about the validity of their axioms in reality.

The most important properties of a system of axioms is its
consistency and its usefulness to build a mathematical theory on it.
Axioms are the start; therefore one cannot derive their truth from
upstream propositions.
Unfortunately it is in general difficult to prove the consistency of
a system of axioms. In rare cases history shows that a system of
axioms is indeed  inconsistent. The most famous example is Russell’s
antinomy which shows the inconsistency of unrestricted set
comprehension.
Besides the axiom system of Euclidean geometry there are axiom
systems of non-Euclidean geometry. All have their value in pure
mathematics. One even has a model of non-Euclidean geometry within
Euclidean geometry.


Interesting! I did not think about the consistency of the axiomatic system (lacking logical contradictions) before! Thank you! I want to understand math philosophy better, and your answer helped me. ^^

@ViktorK. You are welcome, enjoy philosophy of mathematics and philosophy of science.

The formulation of the question (as well as some of the answers) involves a basic misconception about what Hilbert's goals were.  Hilbert did not think that mathematics involves investigation of "arbitrary systems of axioms".  Note that Vladimir Arnold was a brilliant mathematician but he was not known as a careful historian; see this post.  Formalism, as practiced for example by David Hilbert and Abraham Robinson, certainly acknowledges meaningfullness to mathematics, but rejects the idea that infinitary entities in mathematics have a reference in either the physical or any ideal Platonic realm.  Hilbert's metamathematical program sought justification for infinitary mathematics in terms of finitary procedures at the metalevel.  Moreover, Hilbert was deeply interested in applications of mathematics to such fields as relativity theory, with impressive contributions such as the Einstein-Hilbert action.
Characterizing classical mathematics as a game is not a feature of Formalism, though some constructivists tend to describe it that way.  Thus, Errett Bishop criticized classical mathematics as a "game" several times in his 1967 book Foundations of Constructive Analysis.

Are you not overstating your point in the last paragraph? In historical hindsight -- a "game" (in this context) is basically the same as a "mechanical procedure" and wasn't formalism mainly the project to try to show that mathematical truth (including about infinitary entitiies) could be established by mechanical procedures? ("Game" doesn't need to have a pejorative meaning - it mostly highlights behavior according to well-determined rules.)

@mudskipper In game theory for example the term game certainly does not have a pejorative meaning.  However in Bishop's book it does.  Similarly for its use in the question.  The point of Hilbert's project was to develop finitary procedures at the metalevel so as to justify infinitary mathematics at the object language level.  I think the term "finitary procedure" is more precise than "game" because the latter can easily be misunderstood as having Bishopian connotations.

You ask:

Is mathematics a game of axioms/definitions/primitive notions/etc, and their logical consequences, that need not be checked in "reality"/"nature"?

No. Even for pure mathematicians, the nature of building formal systems of mathematical logic requires axioms to observe a certain type of truth known as the coherent theory of truth. Most of the time, the point is to craft formal language that exhibits important properties and those properties rely on how truth operates. Sometimes it means creating mathematical theories that help solve or prove conjectures. The continuum hypothesis is a good example where an extra axiom is needed beyond those of ZFC, and so reverse mathematics is required to fish out a new axiom that is coherent and independent of ZFC.
But, you are asking after what might be called the correspondence theory of truth where language reflects the state of affairs in the world. In this case, the answer for at least applied mathematicians and engineers is also yes, the meanings and significance of axioms matter. In mathematical modeling, the goal is to align mathematical language and logic with the behavior of the physical world. Investment companies, for instance, attempt to model the markets. Both behavorial economics and microeconomics use mathematical systems who axioms are presumed to be measurements of the real world and whose calculations are supposed to be predictive of the state of affairs.
Thus, anyone who uses mathematics to describe and predict the world around them certainly relies on accurate axioms that correspond to the world. In fact, one of the greatest historical moments in mathematics might be the discovery that spacetime can be modeled in non-Euclidean ways. For thousands of years, Euclid's parallel postulate, was presumed to be provable from the other four which were thought to be observations true of space itself. But it turns out, that physically spherical surfaces, for instance, give us an entirely distinct assumption that allows a distinct mathematics model it. Such a geometry is called spherical geometry and it's construction caused quite the uproar among mathematicians initially.
Even for category theorists, the presumptions that go into the system are important because they serve as abstractions of other mathematical systems. For instance, in computer science, functional programming is often described in terms of category theory, and how functions in programming languages relate to how categories behave mathematically means there must be some correspondence between the assumptions about programming functions and those of category theory itself.
Thus, more often than not, mathematical theories are either understood in terms of our intuitions of their axioms in practical terms or are specifically selected or constructed to correspond to physical phenomena. If pure and applied mathematicians paid no attention to what the axioms mean, be that aligning with ideas or measurements in the physical world, mathematics would be fundamentally useless.

Thank you! I had never heard before about the "correspondence theory of truth". I am reading the Wikipedia article about it right now. ^^

That's why we're here. To spread good ideas. And the correspondence theory of truth is a pivotal moment in epistemology, because it laid a more rigorous definition for the term 'truth'. In fact, there are number of theories of truth these days and often times, people arguing over 'truth' are simply struggling to decide which theory is applicable.

Why the curious formatting?

@DavidRoberts Markup adds to semantics and eases location of resources? If I ever decide to scrape my own answer set, internal formatting will be a utility for manipulating the data set. Thanks for poking your head out; I have a deep interest on dependent types as reflected in natural language ontology. Your blog seems fertile.

I'm not an expert in physics, but I think the paragraph which talks about spacetimes and spherical geometry is so well-put. In special relativity, spacetime is Lorentzian, not spherical. In general relativity, the shape is generally quite complicated, but as for the actual universe, AFAIK experimental evidence shows that in large scale it seems to be actually pretty much Euclidean. So I don't really see the point of the reference to spherical geometry in this context.

Also: pure mathematics does not have to be useful, that's not the point. Some correspondence to intuition grounded, often very remotely, in reality, is arguably quite important, but pure mathematicians generally do not care very much about even potential applications.

Yes, they do care.
Formalism is a dead end, mathematicians do not invent arbitrary axiomatic systems and investigate them. Instead, they look at systems with some connection to reality and look at axiomatic systems that organically come up in this process.
Take for example non-Euclidean geometry. This came out of investigating Euclidean plane geometry. It is a generalisation where the parallel axiom is said not to hold.
Often, mathematicians will say the mathmatical objects, read mathematical systems, "come up in nature", which underscores this point.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I find it always helpful when thinking about the philosophy of mathematics to situate it in the context of epistemology in general.
It's worthwhile to think of mathematical formalism as a specifically mathematical form of nominalism - the philosophy that words (or even concepts), particularly words for universals, don't refer to anything at all but are rather a convenience created by humans to help them communicate.  So, for a nominalist, while of course there are individual trees, the idea that they all belong in one category 'tree' is purely a human invention.  This does not preclude there being perfectly good reasons why humans tend to make the category 'tree', but there is no essential reason for it beyond convenience.  For example, birds might have good reasons to distinguish trees in ways so that they are not one category, and dolphins might lump trees in with many other objects that to them are functionally the same.
The lesson here is that 'logically arbitrary' is not the same as 'arbitrary', so it's perfectly reasonable for a formalist to posit that, while there are no purely logical a priori disembodied reasons to study certain collections of axioms rather than others, there are certainly human reasons (including historical and sociological and aesthetic reasons rather than purely natural ones) for humans to study certain collections of axioms.
Note I have said nothing about 'truth' or 'reality' because I find those terms too general and fuzzily defined to be useful in this discussion.

From a biologist's perspective, there’s no such thing as a tree. :)

@IlmariKaronen - Very cool link - - thanks :)

@mudskipper Is it the challenge to natural kinds? Presumably a man of your literacy if familiar with there's no such thing as a fish?

You're such a flatterer @JD. (It's also funny you think I'm a man :) Am I? If there are no fish, how can there be men?) I am familiar with those arguments - I like the link mostly because of the concrete details. -- Btw -- I have a (vague) hypothesis about what kind of people are two-boxers rather than one-boxers in the Newcomb problem. Given some personal info you mentioned in some other comment, I predict you are a one-boxer. Is that correct?

@mudskipper Flatterer? (The threat of an ape; the threat of a flatter; these deserve equal regard. - fragment attributed to Epictetus.) Sorry, I didn't realize you were non-binary. I'll get back to you on the Newcomb problem. Not enough time to read the entire Encyclopedia Galactica.

@JD - Sorry I didn't want to be disingenuous. My self-locating gender question was only philosophical :)

Is mathematics a pure game? In theory it could be. But I trust hedonism enough to assume that mathematicians would not lose their time in writing a totally useless theory even if it happened to be consistent.
In fact there is always - directly or not - a real world question for which the theory can help. But mathematicians expect their theories to be consistent; that is the reason why they try hard to extract a limited number of axioms and derive everything from there. It is then simpler to know where a theory can be used: anywhere the set of axioms is acceptable. Which is not that different from what physicist do: Newtonian mechanics is acceptable for limited masses, relativity is required for very large systems (it is required to explain how Mercury moves around the sun...), and quantum mechanics is the way to go at atomic and sub-atomic scales.
You spoke about Euclid axioms for geometry, and said that they looked consistent with everyday world. One is specifically interesting here: the fifth one aka the parallel postulate. In a plane, through a point not on a given straight line, at most one line can be drawn that never meets the given line. It was negated in the 19th century by Riemann to produce what is sometimes called the elliptic geometry where there are no parallel lines since any two lines must intersect. Not only does this Elliptic geometry have direct usages when you consider the great circles on a sphere (for example on earth...) with concrete implications for computing distances on earth, but it is also heavily used in the relativity theory.
In fact it indeed started more or less for gamification, but it was then heavily developed because it was useful. I would bet a coin that it would not have been so extensively developed without its real world implications.

I would like to expand your citation : '"The question of "truth" of the individual geometrical propositions is thus reduced to one of the "truth" of the axioms. Now it has long been known that the last question (...) it is in itself entirely without meaning (...) The concept "true" does not tally with the assertions of pure geometry, because by the word "true" we are eventually in the habit of designating always the correspondence with a "real" object; geometry, however, is not concerned with the relation of the ideas involved in it to objects of experience, but only with the logical connection of these ideas among themselves.'
In this passage Einstein equate the concept of truth and reality. And we can argue that for him reality is what modern physics and science can proof under experimental condition. In other words, the same terms acquires different meanings according to the context and the author.
About formal mathematics (not physics) it is relevant to recall the incompleteness theorems of Kurt Goedel. His second theorem demonstrated that no formal system can validate its own consistency using only the rules and axioms contained within it.
In other words, for Euclid his axioms were evident as for Einstein his intuitions. For both evidence is a synonym of truth. But what is 'evident'?

I think it depends on whether you're a pure (theoretical) mathematician or an applied mathematician.
If you're doing applied math, it's important that the results are relevant to the real world. The axioms you start with will be based on observations about the universe, and if the math is correct then the results can be used to build things or explain other phenomena. This is the math that engineers, physicists, accountants, and actuaries depend on, for example. If your axioms aren't "true" (at least to a necessary level of precision), the results generally won't be useful. A mathematical system where 1+1=3 is not helpful when you're keeping track of bank accounts.
But if you're doing theoretical math, it's basically sophisticated symbol manipulation. You can start with any axioms you want, it's a "what if this were true?" game.
And sometimes this can change. Much of non-Euclidean geometry was originally considered theoretical. But eventually it found application in the model of space-time in Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.

Speaking as a theoretical mathematician, I do not think this is an accurate description of what we do. It may be formally equivalent to "just symbol manipulation" but nobody thinks about it in that way

@DarkMalthorp https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html is mathematics as symbol manipulation.

@prosfilaes yes, as I said, it's formally equivalent. But nobody would commit their life's work to that unless they thought there was something more profound going on.

@DarkMalthorp Sorry, I didn't intend "just" to mean that it's not important. I've changed it to "sophisticated" to reflect what really goes into the process.

@Barmar I think that it is true theoretically that what we do is symbol manipulation, but we all have a notion (irrational perhaps) that it corresponds to some reality.

@DarkMalthorp Maybe, although it can be a very abstract notion of reality. E.g. when you extend geometry and topology into N dimensions, I think it's mostly an intellectual exercise (but it turns out to have application to string theory). I don't think the creators of complex numbers thought they corresponded to reality (hence the term "imaginary").

@DarkMalthorp Another way to look at is that it doesn't matter if it corresponds to reality. If it does, that's all well and good. But if not, we've still learned something about how mathematical objects behave.

@Barmar well, we don't usually get philosophical about it, so I guess I can't explain exactly what I mean (and btw higher than 3 dimensional geometry has a lot of applications, dimensions aren't only spatial dimensions), but I and my colleagues certainly have a sense that there is some reality to the things we work with. Perhaps Plato was really on to something after all

@DarkMalthorp I don't think there's a hard line, but calling it "theoretical" expresses something divorced from reality.

@Barmar only if you make an assumption like materialism
